# softassert/verify in Serenity with Jbehave BDD framework in Selenium

Tags: selenium, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am working in Automation project with Serenity/JBehave BDD framework and am facing the issue when any step fails in the story, the rest of the steps are not getting executed because of hardassert.

I want to know if there is any softassert like in TestNG or any verify option in Serenity/JBehave.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for soft asserts at the moment is to use Serenity Screenplay (http://thucydides.info/docs/articles/soft-asserts.html), which provides a number of powerful options in this area. We may integrate soft asserts into the general @Step libraries at some point in the future.

Comment: Hi John , Last comment says soft assers might be integrated in future , is it integrated now ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for:

```
    embedderControls.doIgnoreFailureInStories(false);
    embedderControls.doIgnoreFailureInView(false);
```

Only you'd want to change the first one, at least, to true.